# How to parse a date without a year in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm trying to parse a date in ruby on rails so I can get the month and day out of it.

```
 DateTime.parse("07/09") // Works
 DateTime.parse("02/07/1975") // Works
 DateTime.parse("08/26/1983") // Fails 
 DateTime.parse("04/28/1982") // Fails
 DateTime.parse("10/17/1961") // Fails
```

Why would that one fail?  There are several others that fail too, with no common thread that I can see.

Comment: `DateTime.parse('11/04')` assumes 2013, and returns a DateTime value of `2013-11-04T00:00:00+00:00`, which is entirely sensible. In what way does it fail?

Comment: @theTinMan could possibly be his version of ruby

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.9.3.  And you're absolutely right.  I saw the invalid date and assumed it was the 11/04.  But this is what actually comes back invalid "08/26/1983".  Why would that be? I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `DateTime.parse("xx/xx/xxxx")` assumes you're giving it the format `DateTime("dd/mm/yyyy")`, i.e. the way that makes sense to most of the world outside the US.  The last three examples don't work because there isn't a 26th, 28th, or 17th month.  Notice that your second example works, but it probably doesn't give you what you think:

```
 DateTime.parse("02/07/1975").month # => 7
```

Instead of `parse`, use `strptime` so you can be explicit about the format from which to parse the date:

```
DateTime.strptime("02/07/1975", "%m/%d/%Y")
DateTime.strptime("02/07/1975", "%m/%d/%Y").month # => 2
```

Comment: The format isn't always the same. And how do I account for locale?

Comment: But you're right, I do have reversed months and days in my db.

Comment: That's a problem you'll have to solve.  `DateTime#parse` is nice in that it magically handles many input formats, but in a format like `07/08/1980` which is ambiguous across the world, Ruby had to pick one interpretation.  Unfortunately, it's not the interpretation you normally work with, so you'll have to deal with it some other way.  You might want to have your own helper class which parses dates, delegating to `DateTime` in every case except the ambiguous one(s).

Comment: You can't account for locale. The origin of the data is only one hint as to the order of month and day, but the data could have come from some other place else entirely. The best answer is when you're in charge of the data, and can then use an ISO format that removes the ambiguity. Or, if you know who generates the data, *ask* them what it is. Otherwise, you might be able to improve your guess-rate by looking through all the date records to see if any others fail the `%m/%d` parse step. If so, rewind your file and reload using `%d/%m` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try `strptime` in DateTime. It receives a format string.

[Documentation on ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime)

Comment: Nevermind, the date I assumed was failing wasn't the one that was failing.  I've update the question.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Your problem stems from the fact that Ruby has several date- and time-related classes. These include:

- [Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)
- [Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html)
- [DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html)

Each of the classes varies in its capabilities and implementation details, but only Time will even parse your particular string. For example:

```
Date.new "08/26/1983"
# => ArgumentError: comparison of String with 0 failed

DateTime.new "08/26/1983"
# => ArgumentError: comparison of String with 0 failed

Time.new "08/26/1983"
# => 0008-01-01 00:00:00 -0500
```

Obviously, it is not the year 0008 A.D., so you need to pass a structured date that your selected date class understands.

### Solution

You need to specify the format of your date string using [#strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime). For example:

```
Date.strptime('08/26/1983', '%m/%d/%Y').to_s
# => "1983-08-26"

DateTime.strptime('08/26/1983', '%m/%d/%Y').to_s
# => "1983-08-26T00:00:00+00:00"
```

you can then use formatting methods provided by your chosen class, such as [DateTime#strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) or [DateTime#rfc2822](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-rfc2822) to format the output in whatever way your application requires.

### Use GNU Date Instead

If you have access to GNU date, you can take advantage of its more liberal parsing. You may still run into issues with locale, but in general GNU date is pretty robust. For example:

```
%x(date -d 1983/08/26).chomp
# => "Fri Aug 26 00:00:00 EDT 1983"

%x(date -d 08/26/1983).chomp
=> "Fri Aug 26 00:00:00 EDT 1983"
```

I don't think GNU date accepts input dates in European order (e.g. `dd/mm/yyyy`) but will certainly honor locale in the output. That shouldn't matter for your use case, but seems worth mentioning for future visitors.

Comment: The problem isn't that Ruby has several classes to manage dates, it's that some dates are ambiguous, and it's impossible for code to know how to handle them. Having Time and Date/DateTime is a legacy thing supported by many languages due to the need to handle hardware/system clocks vs. software/extended date ranges. It's just one of many things a programmer needs to be aware of when dealing with dates and times, akin to working with ASCII vs. multi-byte characters. LOCALE is a hint for output, but not much help when parsing.

Answer (score 0):

One of the important things about parsing dates is to be in control. Ruby's designers made a good decision to assume `12/1/2000` is in `"DD/MM/YYYY"` format, because it's for the common good, it just rubs us 'Mericans wrong, but, then again, we have weird rulers, spell "color" funny, and drive on the wrong side of the road too.

Because we know our dates are in a weird format we can use [`Date.strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) or [`DateTime.strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) or `Time.strptime` to specify the actual format the date is in. Use `'%m/%d/%Y'` for leading months, or `'%d/%m/%Y'` for the rest of us... them... whichever.

Date, DateTime and Time have the `parse` method also, which is able to handle a lot of different formats, but will choke on that one month vs. day issue. I use them as starting points in code if I am confident I won't have a collision with 'Merican vs. everyone-else dates.

If you don't know your date data's source, one tactic is to start a parse of the file using `'%m/%d'` format, and `rescue` the parsing error. If you encounter one, which is kind-of likely, [`rewind`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-rewind) the file and `retry` the load using `'%d/%m'` format.

Or... for true flexibility, look at the almost-insanely awesome [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) gem. It will still trip over the `%m/%d` vs. `%d/%m` issue, but that can't be helped.

There is no way software can make an good decision over the date format, even by looking at LOCALE settings or knowing the longitude/latitude coordinates of the incoming data because data can come from anywhere.